# Magnetic Susceptibility- Permeability

Tags: electricity

What is the permeability of magnesium sulphate and therefore the magnetic susceptibility?

Comment: Google for "Handbook of Chemistry and Physics". Note that [there is a meta discussion that concerns this question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/should-general-reference-questions-be-closed-on-physics-se) among others.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search yielded this web page/pdf.

[Table of Magnetic Susceptibilities](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http://www-d0.fnal.gov/hardware/cal/lvps_info/engineering/elementmagn.pdf&ei=b10vT-XOJ6eL2AW838mHDw&usg=AFQjCNGPMVkvo-lOb0GRd_fXzRqmDtUkFg)

You will have to wade through their units, but they are seemingly explicit.

Hope this helps.